# flutter remote access to woocommerce with getx flutter

Tags: api, flutter, dart

i'm trying to connect TO my woocommerce through api but it shows me error 401

```
class RemoteServices{
static var client = http.Client();
static Future<List<Welcome>> fetchProducts() async{
var response =await client.get("https://mywebsite/wp-json/wc/v3/products",headers: <String,String>{'Usermname':('ck_key'),'Password':'cs_key' });
  if(response.statusCode==200){
    var jsontString = response.body;
    return welcomeFromJson(jsontString);
    
  }
  else{
    print("error api");
    print(response.statusCode);
  }
}
}
```

and it's always shows me error 401

Comment: 401 mean Unauthorized problem https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401

Answer (score 0):

Your url is not being built properly the way you're trying to do it.

This is an example of one way to do this with `GetConnect`

```
final map = {'apikey': 'yourApiKey'}; //equivalent to adding apiKey=yourApiKey to the url
final response = await client.get("https://mywebsite/wp-json/wc/v3/products", headers: map);
```

You also don't have to use the headers property in the `get` call either. If you're new to calling Apis then the easier way to start out would be to pass the full complete url into the `get` method and that works fine as well.

Either way, you need to confirm what the right url should be in your browser, then make sure you're passing that into the `get` function.